# Instrument does not change in Jfugue

Tags: java, jfugue

I am running the Jfugue test program, here is the code:

```
package ge;

import org.jfugue.*;

public class GE {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Player player = new Player();
       Pattern pattern = new Pattern("C D E F G A B I[MARIMBA]");
       player.play(pattern);
       System.exit(0); // If using Java 1.4 or lower
    }
}
```

The code does work so far, that is, it compiles and the notes are played. However, I can change the instrument around however much I wish, I always get piano music.

How can I change this?

Answer (score 5):

You should set the instrument at the beginning of the sequence, not at the end of it. Sequence `"I[MARIMBA] C D E F G A B"` is played as a marimba instrument for me.

Comment: The author of JFugue is chiming in to say that @Archeg's answer should be accepted as the correct answer!